# Poincaré Transformation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

**Exercise:** Let $\;p\in\mathcal{U}\subset\mathbb{R}^{d}$ a periodic point and $P:S'\rightarrow S$ the Poincaré transformation associated to transversal section $S$ in $p$. Let $z\in S$ such that $P^n(z)=f^{t_n}(z)$ is defined for all $n\geq0$ and
\begin{equation}
\|P^n(z)-p\|\leq C\lambda^{n}, \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)
\end{equation}
with $C>0$ and $\lambda<1$. Show that the orbit of $z$ is assymptotic to orbit of $f^r(p)$, for some $r\in\mathbb{R}$.

**Attempt:**

Given $P^n(z)=f^{t_n}(z)$, we have $\tau(P^n(z))=t_{n+1}-t_n$, where $\tau:S'\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the *return time* function, and $\tau\in C^k$.$\;$ As $\tau\in C^k$, then $\;t_{n+1}-t_n \rightarrow \tau(p)=T$, where $T>0\;$ is the period. In particular, exists $n_0\geq1$ such that, for all $n\geq n_0$
$$t_{n+1}-t_n < T+1.$$
By Continuous Dependence Theorem, given $\epsilon>0$, exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$\|x-p\| \leq\delta \Rightarrow \|f^s(x)-f^s(p)\|\leq\epsilon,\; \forall s\in[0,T+1].$$
The condition $(1)$ says that $P^n(z)$ converges exponentially to $p$, but I don't know how use this to prove.

Any help would be appreciated!